# Handling unique constraint exceptions inside transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two Rails models / tables that I want insert as part of transaction.

For example, here are roughly my tables:

- Posts: (id)
- Comments: (id, post_id, comment_text, user_id)
- Commenters: (id, post_id, user_id), unique constraint on (post_id,
  user_id)

Right now I'm trying approximately equivalent to:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  Comment.create!(post: post, user: user, comment_text: '...')

  begin
    Commenters.find_or_create_by!(post: post, user: user)
  rescue PG::UniqueViolation
  end
end
```

This works 99.9% of time, but sometimes two concurrent comments will trigger a PG::UniqueViolation.

Even though I'm catching and suppressing the PG::UniqueViolation, the entire transaction fails due to:

**ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block**

I realize I could already achieve this by joining Post and Comment table, but this is a simplified example.

Is there a simpler way to ensure both inserts happen as part of a transaction while still ignoring the unique violation since we can assume that the record already exists?

Answer (score 2):

An exception raised inside the transaction does two things:

1. Rolls back the transaction so none of the changes made inside the transaction will persist in the database.
2. The exception propagates outside the transaction block.

So you can move your exception handler outside the `transaction` call:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    Comment.create!(post: post, user: user, comment_text: '...')
    Commenters.find_or_create_by!(post: post, user: user)
  end
rescue PG::UniqueViolation
  retry
end
```

You could include a counter to only retry a few times if you wanted more safety.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the associations properly set inside your models, so rails does the validation for you. Then you can simply rescue the possible `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` (with message `Validation failed:` *Attribute* `has already been taken`).

If you want to read some more about uniqueness validtion this should come in handy: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

To me it actually looks like your `Commenter` model is not really necessary. It just consists of derived information which can also be drawn directly from the `Comments` model (there you already store `post_id` and `user_id`) so you could drop the `Commenter` class entirely. Then take care to validate `Comment` on creation by for example setting

```
class Comment
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user
 validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :post_id}
end
```

But this way you would allow a user to comment only once.

I propose you drop the uniqueness constraint and construct the information stored in `Commenter` by making `distinct` selects on the `Comment` model.

PS: Models in rails are written in Uppercase and singular while tables are referred to (by symbols) in lowercase and plural.

Comment: Right, as mentioned, this isn't the actual code, just a similar example. I don't think a Rails validation would help here since due to concurrency the exception could still be raised: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: You might want to read the guide you linked to more carefully, the "you must create a unique index on that column in your database" in particular. Uniqueness validations are never enough.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how it is setup. The unique index/constraint is what raises the PG:UniqueViolation mentioned in the question due to concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself happens because of multi-threading behaviour of your app.

You need to rescue **ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique**  instead of PG-specific error.

Also perhaps put transaction inside begin rescue end block.
And retry to continue with another transaction within rescue block. Something like another answer suggested.